# Access: Entering multiple subform values with one entry in the form

Tags: ms-access, subform

I've been using Access to create simple databases for a while with great success, but have run into a problem I can't find an answer to.

We ship individualized serialized units to various end-users, and occasionally to resellers that stock them for end-users. I must keep track of which serial numbers end up with each end-users.

The first database I created to handle this recorded company information in one table using their account number as primary key, order information in a second table using the order number as the primary key and linked via the company name, and unit information in a third table with the serial number as the primary key and linked via the order number.

This worked very well until I had to account for these stock orders with a reseller. As it was structured, every unit was linked to one company via the sales order. The issue is that I may ship 20 units on one order to Company A, who then sells 5 to Company B and 3 to Company C.

I realized I needed to link the company name directly to the units, not the orders and have fixed that.

My issue now is simplicity in entering information in the form. My previous database involved the employee in our shipping department merely entering the sales order, selecting the customer name from a drop down menu, then scanning the serial numbers in a subform. This was to ensure simplicity and try to eliminate human error. He had only three things to input, and most of the input was done by scanning barcodes.

As it is currently structured now, the employees out in shipping would have to populate the company name for every record in the subform with the serial number and that complicates things in a way that is unacceptable. At the point of shipping, the company name will always be the same for every unit in the subform.

So.

How would I go about creating a form where the company name is entered once in the form, and automatically populates itself for every record in the subform?  The caveat here is that I must also be able to go back occasionally and change the company name of individual units in an order without necessarily affecting the rest of the order. I suppose it starts out as a one-to-many relationship that then must be able to change.

I hope that makes sense.

I have looked for answers using various approaches with auto-fill and relationships and not preserving data integrity, but I feel the answer is just beyond my reach.

The only solution I can think of is to create another field in the unit table for the end-user, and perhaps write a formula that sets this default value as the company name from the order that shipped it. This seems unnecessarily complicated and redundant, there has to be a better way.

Comment: Your question requires insight at two different layers, the layer of tables and columns, and the layer of forms and sub forms.  If you are accustomed to letting the wizard create your forms for you, as I am, it can be difficult to unlink these two layers.  It sounds like you're ok with the tables and columns, although more detail might enable us to review your work.  Your question can be improved by being more specific about what you're looking for in the way of forms and sub forms.

Comment: Please provide a schema. We need table names and corresponding column names, cleanly laid out, and specifying what the inputs are and what the output should be. There are definitely some techniques for populating several tables with a single form entry but I'm not sure if that's what you're asking here. Cut out the maze of text please :-)